# Why doesn't android:colorBackground work on some devices?

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, material-components

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">#26A69A</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I want to know why `android:colorBackground` doesn't work on some devices. I ran the app on the API `21 (Not working)`, `24 (Not Working)`, and `29 (Working)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now after I changed it like this

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/myColor</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```